# Q: Chart.js v2 - x-axis time scale configuration

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, chart.js, momentjs

I have problem to setting the X axys in line chart.
I have many data sets like this

```
        dataset_1 = [{
         x: '10:00'
         y: 12.4
        },{
         x: '12:00'
         y: 9.3
        },{
         x: '14:00'
         y: 10.9
        }]

        dataset_2 = [{
         x: '8:43'
         y: 5.7
        },{
         x: '9:00'
         y: 11.4
        },{
         x: '10:00'
         y: 9.6
        }]

      ecc... (i create this with ajax query)

newDataset.data.push('{x: ' + x_data + ',y: ' + y_data + '}');
chartData.data.datasets.push(newDataset);
```

I would need help to format the x axis option to view from 00:00 to 23:59 with 15 or 30 minute step on x axis without any warning to format or parsing data in option or datasets.

For example

```
  |
 7-
  |
  |    . x 8:43
 5-      y 5.7
  |
  |
  --|-----|-----|----
    8:00  9:00 10:00
```

I try with many examples but don't work

```
xAxes: [{
    type: 'time',
    time: {
     displayFormats: {
        minute: 'HH:mm'
         }
       }
    }]
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: `but don't work` Post the code you're trying to work with and people might be able to help

Comment: I added more more specific code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instancing the chart you need to put this:

```
var start = new Date();
start.setHours(0,0,0,0);
var end = new Date();
end.setHours(23,59,59,999)
chartLine = new Chart(chartEl, {
    ...
    options: {
        ...
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                type: 'time',
                time: {
                    minUnit: 'minute',
                    unit: 'minute',
                    unitStepSize: 30,
                    min: start,
                    max: end
                },
                ...
            }
            ...
        }
    }
}
```